# VS Code: "Error opening connection connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" when trying to connect to database

Tags: visual-studio-code, xampp, sqltools

I have xampp installed on linux mint and now i want to connect vs code to the sql-database.

I have installed the extension SQLTools and created a connection to the database with the correct credentials but then i get an error: `Error opening connection connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`.

The error is the same also when i try using other extensions like vscode-database or SQL Server (mssql).

I really would appreciate help to this.

Answer (score 1):

i now have added `i now have added in the settings the socket path:`
"socketPath": "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock"` to my settings.json.

then i installed mysql-server and executed the following query in the mysql workbench: 
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword'`

now i'm able to log in to the later added mysql server but still not to the mysql server in lampp. When i try to connect then i get the error `Error opening connection ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'my_database'

I've also tried different ports like 80 or 8889 but that didn't help. Does someone have an idea what to do?

`

Answer (score 0):

If you had restarted your computer, here is a fix that helped me out.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

install mysql on windows...
see on "services" if MYsql are there.